# How to open project properties for startup project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio, is there any quick way to open project properties for the chosen startup project without having to open solution explorer and tediously go find it? Perhaps a keyboard shortcut or menu item.

Comment: Well, sure, rename the project to "Aardvark".

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature to do that, perhaps you can do that by some Extension. you can only assign a shortcut to open the The selected/active project property.